# Received Mockery_0_Illuminate_Cache_CacheManager::driver(), but no expectations were specified

Tags: laravel, mocking

I have this simple test below:

```
public function test_return_success_if_reminder_is_set(){
        Cache::shouldReceive('remember')
            ->once()
            ->with($this->user->email, 60, \Closure::class)
            ->andReturn([
                "message" => "Cool"
            ]);

        $response = $this->json("POST", "my-awesome-endpoint");

        $response->assertStatus(200)
            ->assertJson([
                "success"=>true,
                "message"=> "Awesome"
            ]);
    }
```

For some reason, I'm getting this error:

```
Received Mockery_0_Illuminate_Cache_CacheManager::driver(), but no expectations were specified
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

```
        Cache::shouldReceive('remember')
        ->once()
        ->with($this->user->email, 60, \Closure::class)
        ->andReturn([
            "message" => "Cool"
        ]);
        Cache::makePartial();
```

Please try the code above

see: http://docs.mockery.io/en/latest/reference/partial_mocks.html?highlight=runtime

Comment: Thanks @yellowman. Your suggestion fixed the error I was having. However, I'm not getting `InvalidArgumentException: Cache store [] is not defined` while I have `<env name="CACHE_DRIVER" value="array"/>` in my `phpunit.xml` file. Any idea on what could be the reason?

Comment: I'm using laravel 5.6 by the way

Comment: sorry, I has not been solved this problem yet.

This problem happen this code, `$name = $name ?: $this->getDefaultDriver();`  at CacheManager.php (  https://github.com/illuminate/cache/blob/master/CacheManager.php#L56)

`$this->getDefaultDriver()` is empty. getDefaultDriver() define `$this->app['config']['cache.default'];`.
(https://github.com/illuminate/cache/blob/master/CacheManager.php#L267)

Furthermore, the timing at which this problem occurs is this.
(https://github.com/illuminate/cache/blob/master/CacheServiceProvider.php#L28)

Comment: (continuation) $app['cache'] object is Mockery_2_Illuminate_Cache_CacheManager.

Comment: Probably, not  load config/cache.php.

Comment: Thanks @yellowsman. The  Cache::makePartial(); did the trick for me .:)

Answer (score 1):

Please, try below code. I did well. :)

```
public function setUp()
{
    Cache::shouldReceive('get')->with('key')->andReturn('value');
    Cache::makePartial();

    parent::setUp();

    // other init code...
}
```